# How to link a dylib with another dylib in the same directory?

Tags: xcode, macos, linker, rpath

I am porting a program to Mac. The program uses a dynamic library which I have compiled into a dylib using xcode. That library again uses a second library, libusb specifically. I have also compiled this into a dylib.

The two dylibs are in the same folder, the installation folder. However this does not work. It only works if I move the second libusb dylib into the /usr/local/lib folder. How can I make it so that the first library is able to link with the second library when they are both in the same folder?

I am guessing I need to edit the runpath of the first library, but I don't know what to write to make the path relative rather than absolute.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I believe you're looking for `install_name_tool` (should be in `/usr/bin/install_name_tool`) which assists with re-establishing dylib reference paths in macOS binaries, for exactly the problem you've described. You could run it as a build phase script to force the correct rpath of the dylib giving you trouble.

Comment: So what should I set the reference paths to? As far as I understand I can't just use a relative path like "./". And the absolute path might vary from system to system.

Comment: `install_name_tool` accepts the special path condition `@executable_path` such that...

`@executable_path/whatever/folder/structure/inside/your/app_file/libusb.dylib`

Comment: Thanks, one more question. Does @executable_path point to the path of the main application, or the dylib?

Comment: The main application. Found a nice write-up on the matter with some options I wasn't aware of, to boot.

https://wincent.com/wiki/@executable_path,_@load_path_and_@rpath